# Assign Dynamic values in Annotations

Tags: java, reflection

I have an custom annotation called "InHouse".

```
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InHouse {

public String[] parentClassNames() default {};
}
```

I applied this annotation in one my POJO class like

```
public class Person{

    @InHouse(parentClassNames={"com.amar.Contact"})
    public Contact contact;
}
```

Like this I specified my annotation. So when I specified a values (parentClassNames) I hard coded the fully qualified class name instead is there any way to access like **"Contact.class.getName()"**. When I use this I am getting a compilation problem. So how can I achieve this...?

**I want like this.**

```
public class Person{

    @InHouse(parentClassNames={Contact.class.getName()})
    public Contact contact;
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible because reflect classes names cant be known at compile time.
You can try to change annotation value param type to Class[]. Then you can use it like you want :

```
@Target(value = ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface InHouse {

    public Class[] parentClassNames() default {};
}

public class Person{

    @InHouse(parentClassNames={Integer.class, String.class}) //Integer and String 
//are just as example, i know they are final and cant be parent classes :)
    public Contact contact;
}
```

It is not hard to get a class name from Class object when you will process that annotation later.